# Salesforce chatter to yammer data migration

Tags: chatter, data, migration

We are working on a migration project from Salesforce to Sharepoint. We are looking for option to migrate Salesforce Chatter data to Yammer. Could you please suggest a best way to migrate chatter data (including chatter attachments) to yammer.

Comment: You should use an ETL, be rigorous on the mapping and the documentations, create external IDs in destination system for the junctures and for tracking purpose, what got rejected and for what reason. Perform several repetitions in testing environments (low volumetry to check the mapping and rules => high volumetry afterwoods). Warning : Make sure the running machine will be able to deal with the attachments in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly make use of any iPaaS tools / ETL from app-exchange by which you can maintain data integrity ,eliminate duplicates . Also you can download attachments from salesforce to local directory & move to other target like yammer.